# Mockito cannot find defined class while running a test

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I am having trouble with mockito dependencies.I wrote a sample test and when I ran it I got this exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist/NotFoundException
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.TestClassTransformerBuilder$RemovesTestMethodAnnotation.fromMethods(TestClassTransformerBuilder.java:62)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDefaultMockLoader(AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:126)
....
```

the full Exception can be viewed at : https://pastebin.com/xWqUX0Wc
and the
test code - https://pastebin.com/pbWLc27B

My dependencies are the following:

```
mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
powermock-api-mockito-1.6.3.jar
powermock-api-support-1.4.9.jar
powermock-core-2.0.4.jar
powermock-module-junit-1.7.4.jar
powermock-module-junit-common-1.7.4.jar
powermock-reflect-2.0.4.jar
powermock-test-utils-1.5.3.jar
```

Where can be the problem?I guess something is wrong with the version of the jars.What version of the jars would you suggest to use ?

Comment: Do not add the source code and error messages on external sites. Please [edit] your question to include these information in your question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your are missing JavaAssist jar download below jars and add them into your projects or add them in maven pom.xml file.

```
<javaassist.version>3.20.0-GA</javaassist.version>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
             <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
             <version>${javaassist.version}</version>
             <scope>compile</scope>
         </dependency>
```